# How to inspect webview in samsung s2 GT-I9100 using chrome

Tags: android, debugging, user-interface, inspect

I am using windows 7 and Eclipse (Android Developer tools). I am able to inspect android 4.4 devices (i.e: samsung S4) but am not able to inspect the Samsung SII GT-I9100 device, may be because of its android version 4.1. can somebody please help me is there any way to inspect Samsung SII Apps?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Remote Debugging on Android with Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging#requirements), remote app debugging is supported only from Android 4.4 onwards. Try [weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/).